Next Auth v5 logout if an API throws 401 error
I am using Next 14 and Next Auth v5 for authentication using credentials provider. I want to handle a case where if an API throws a 401 error from the backend, then logout the user in the background and refresh the page.
I am handling all the API calls within a single util file and using it across the application.
Apiclient.js
import { getSession } from "@/lib/utils";

async function apiClient({
  path,
  options = {},
  headers = {},
  tags,
  cache = "force-cache",
}) {
  const session = await getSession();
  const token = session?.user?.accessToken;
  console.log(token);
  try {
    const mergedOptions = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        ...(token && { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }),
        isGuest: token ? false : true,
        ...headers,
      },
      ...options,
      cache: cache,
      ...(tags && { next: { tags: [tags] } }),
    };

    const response = await fetch(path, mergedOptions);
  
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

export default apiClient;

Below is one of the example where I am using this client with server action functions.
"use server";
import Link from "next/link";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import {
  NavBar,
  Logo,
  UserDropdown,
  NavMobile,
  CategoryMenu,
} from "@/components/common";
import { Search, LocaleSwitcher } from "@/components/ui";
import { CartIcon, MiniCart } from "@/components/cart";
import { getUserSessionServer } from "@/lib/utils/getUserSessionServer";
import { getCart } from "@/framework/server-actions/cart";
import { getNavigation } from "@/framework/server-actions/menu";
import {
  WishlistProducts,
  RefreshUserSession,
  HeaderWrapper,
} from "@/components/common";

const Header = async () => {
  const cartId = cookies().get("cartId");
  const sessionPromise = await getUserSessionServer();
  const cartPromise = cartId && (await getCart());
  const menuPromise = await getNavigation();

  const [session, cart, menu] = await Promise.all([
    sessionPromise,
    cartPromise,
    menuPromise,
  ]);

  return (
    <HeaderWrapper>
      <div className="md:relative">
        <div className="md:max-w-screen-xl mx-auto">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <div className="hidden sm:block">
              <ul className="space-x-8 text-white text-sm sm:flex rtl:space-x-reverse">
                <li>
                  <CategoryMenu links={menu} />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link href={"/cms/about-us"}>About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link href={"/contact-us"}>Contact</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="md:absolute md:start-1/2 md:-translate-x-1/2 rtl:md:translate-x-1/2 top-0">
              <Logo />
            </div>
            <div className="">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <Search />
                <LocaleSwitcher />
                <CartIcon cartTotalsInfo={cart} />
                <UserDropdown session={session} />
                <NavMobile links={menu} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <MiniCart
        session={session}
        cartTotalsInfo={cart}
        WishlistProducts={
          <WishlistProducts
            session={session}
            className="embla__product__minicart embla__product__container__minicart"
          />
        }
      />
      <RefreshUserSession />
    </HeaderWrapper>
  );
};

export default Header;

I have tried adding this to my apiClient and handling the logout on client side
if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
      console.log("response.status", response.status);
      return "unauthorized";
    }

"use client";
import { useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { Link } from "@/i18n/routing";
import { IconBagWhite } from "@/assets";
import { CartContext } from "@/contexts/CartContext";
import { logout } from "@/framework/server-actions/account/access";

const CartIcon = ({ cartTotalsInfo }) => {
  const isCheckout = usePathname() === "/checkout";
  const { setShowMiniCart } = useContext(CartContext);
  const { itemsQuantity } = cartTotalsInfo || {};

  const handleOpenMiniCart = useCallback(
    () => setShowMiniCart(true),
    [setShowMiniCart]
  );

  if (cartTotalsInfo === "unauthorized") {
    console.log("cartTotalsInfo is", cartTotalsInfo);
    logout();
    console.log("logged out, router refresh", cartTotalsInfo);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isCheckout ? (
        <Link href="/cart" className="block relative">
          <IconBagWhite />
          {itemsQuantity > 0 && (
            <div className="absolute -top-2 h-[20px] w-[20px] rounded-full bg-red-600 -end-1 ">
              <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-[11px] font-bold text-white">
                {itemsQuantity}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Link>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button
            className="relative items-center px-2 hidden sm:flex"
            onClick={handleOpenMiniCart}
          >
            <IconBagWhite />
            {itemsQuantity > 0 && (
              <div className="absolute -top-2 h-[20px] w-[20px] rounded-full bg-red-600 -end-1 ">
                <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-[11px] font-bold text-white">
                  {itemsQuantity}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </button>
          <Link href="/cart" className="block relative sm:hidden">
            <IconBagWhite />
            {itemsQuantity > 0 && (
              <div className="absolute -top-2 h-[20px] w-[20px] rounded-full bg-red-600 -end-1 ">
                <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-[11px] font-bold text-white">
                  {itemsQuantity}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </Link>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default CartIcon;

After logout I want to fetch all the data again

So far I see all your throw declarations as commented out. Are those intentional?

@Sarkis Yes I have commented intentionally to debug. Do you have any idea how we can resolve this and make a robust solution

It's always a good idea to use AI to generate a boilerplate code as a starting point, but copy pasting it as is on stackoverflow with multiple consecutive questions stands against the guidelines and kinda lazy IMO.
Maybe refactor the code and filter your question down into a single one so the community will better address your needs.
Cheers!
